# can you tell me anything about this bike. frame/brakes, etc

Tags: brakes, frames, carbon

my friend inherited this bike. curious what he has. thank you!
[image]

Comment: "my friend" and "inherited" both sound kinda suspicious, just FYI.

Comment: Hopefully they also inherited the original bar, stem and saddle and can put them back on

Answer (score 1):

It is what I'd call a flat-bar commuter bike, though others would call it a Hybrid or Fitness bike.

The frame says

Brand: Specialized
Model: Sirrus

The current lineup is pictured at **https://www.specialized.com/us/en/shop/bikes/active-bikes/fitness--hybrid-bikes/sirrus/c/sirrus#/filter:braketype:Rim**  according to google.  I can't see one with the same red-line accents so its not a current model

The barends and mirror look like add-ons, and the saddle looks like someone wanted a softer one.

As long as its comfortable for you to ride, you should get many miles of usage out of it.  Enjoy your bike.

Answer (score 1):

Without meaning to be condescending, the frame manufacturer (e.g. Specialized) is almost always on the decals. Some frames have the model name as well (e.g. Sirius). This is a start for a Google search.

The seat stays have a polymer insert at a bend. Specialized branded these Zertz, and they are supposed to add comfort. Based on that, I’d guess this frame originates from the earlier part of the 2010s.

It has what we call rim brakes, as opposed to disc brakes. These are perfectly fine brakes, but they do mean you can’t use really wide and comfortable tires (e.g. 32mm or wider). This may not be a terrible deficit depending on the terrain. You can likely mount up to 28mm tires, which are pretty comfortable already.

I know less about the Sirrus than other models, but that information may be a start.